# random.uniform() часто дает одинаковые значения

Tags: python, случайные-числа

При частом обращении к `random.uniform()` я получаю много одинаковых чисел. Связано ли это с сидом, зависящим от времени на моем пк? Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар показывает вероятность того, что вы перед каждым `random.uniform()` делаете `random.seed()`. Если это так, тогда, конечно, при частом вызове будет давать одинаковые числа. `random.seed()` нужно вызывать один раз в начале работы программы.

Answer (score 3):

А давайте проверим правдивость ваших слов:

Сгенерируем 100000 случайных чисел с помощью random.uniform, причем сделаем это на маленьком диапазоне  -  всего-то от 0 до 1. И посмотрим, сколько среди них одинаковых

```
import random
lt=[]
for i in range(100000):
    lt.append(random.uniform(0,1))
print(len(set(lt)))
```

Ответ  -  сгенерировано 100000 чисел НИ ОДНО ИЗ КОТОРЫХ не повторятся. Так что что-то вы делаете неправильно.  Покажите, где и как вы заметили повторяющиеся элементы у себя в коде.

Comment: Я почему-то решил, что числа будут целые. Только в этом случае какие-то повторы могут быть. Ждём код автора вопроса. )